# Morphia - Map single collection data into multiple pojos

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a collection with 40 fields.

I have pojo as follows

```
@Entity("colName")
public class Entity1 {
   //Id
   //10 fields - names same as collection columns
   @Embedded
   //Entity2
}
```

Entity2 class:

```
@Embedded
public class Entity2 {
  //20 other fields
}
```

I query the collection as follows

```
datastore.createQuery(Entity1.class).disableValidation().filter("fieldFromEntity1", "2227536").asList();
```

But I get always Entity2 reference as null.

I found that Entity2 has to be nested document.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Document:**

```
{
 _id: a|b|c,
 field1: stringValue,
 ....
 field40: intgerValue
}
```

Comment: can you share what that document looks like in the database?

Comment: @evanchooly Please find the attached format. Out of 40 fields, I have 10 in one pojo including id and others are in another pojo. I need this for REST API response format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphia doesn't directly support what you need.  However, you can use `@Preload` and `@Presave` to manipulate the shapes of documents on their way to/from the database.  I think you could also just use, say, Jackson annotations to name/nest those fields when serializing out to json.  That'd be the simplest approach.